# How can I make Visual Studio copy a specific file to the publish directory?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, publish

I am using the `Publish` feature of Visual Studio to create a ClickOnce setup file for my VSTO add-in.

I know that I can cause files to be deployed together with the application by setting their Build Action to `Content`. Let's say I have a file called `readme.txt`, whose Build Action is set to `Content`. This is what happens:

```
publish
+-- setup.exe
+-- MyAddIn.vsto
+-- ApplicationFiles
    +-- ...lots of files..
    +-- readme.txt.deploy     <--
```

Since the file contains information that I want the user to read *before* installing the application, this is what I *want* to happen:

```
publish
+-- setup.exe
+-- MyAddIn.vsto
+-- readme.txt                 <--
+-- ApplicationFiles
    +-- ...lots of files..
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the project file:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)readme.txt&quot; &quot;$(PublishUrl)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Here's what I was working on in case this more general scenario is useful for others:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ReadmeFilesDir>README-files</ReadmeFilesDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)README.html&quot; &quot;$(PublishUrl)&quot;" />
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe /E /I /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)$(ReadmeFilesDir)&quot; &quot;$(PublishUrl)$(ReadmeFilesDir)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

<sup><sup>*I wonder if there's a badge for answering a six year-old question.*</sup></sup>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use a post-build command to move the file to the location you want, then the wizard will package the folder as is.